# VSCODE JUPYTER - How to display SAME AUTOCOMPLETION in notebooks (.ipynb) as it is in python (.py) from VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete

I am using **Jupyter Notebook inside VSCODE** and was happy with it until I found out this issue.

The autocompletion seems not to be working well inside Notebooks compared to the regular Python script as shown on the screenshots below.

If someone already faced this problem any infos will be welcomed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've not installed `ipykernel` package. You can install it like that

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Comment: I re-installed it and it work properly now, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install the extension "Pylance" in VS Code and use the language service provided by "Pylance": use it in the "[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)" of VS Code:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

[image]

Comment: I re-installed it and it work properly now, good to know thanks you